# Does Mountain lion download Apple's JDK or the OpenJDK when attempting to load a Java app?

Tags: java, macos

When you first try and load a Java application (eclipse, run mvn commands etc) Lion prompted you to download a JRE/JDK. From my understanding this is still Apple's version of Java and not OpenJDK.  Will Mountain Lion still have Apple's Java available the same way or will it prompt you to download OpenJDK?

Comment: Oracle has a JRE 1.7 for OSX, but installation and activation is hard: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prompts you (just tried to open Aptana). I let it install and

```
java -version
```

gives

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Nice, no open jdk yet

Comment: For the comment: http://jdk7.java.net/macportpreview/ recently redirects to http://jdk7.java.net/download.html with developer preview releases for multiple platforms so I guess that the port for OS X is now on a par with those other ports. I guess that the wait, for Oracle's greater (version 7) distribution to become mainstream on OS X, should be not too long. For the plug-in, there's a suggestion "[As soon as the Mac version is available, we will add a link here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/mac-138071.html)" … I wonder whether that page has been forgotten or overlooked by Oracle …

Comment: given that we're not ready to move to 1.7 yet, I hope Apple doesn't remove the ability to download 1.6 any time soon.