# How can I upgrade from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 8 using Homebrew and be sure it will be used by default?

Tags: macos, mac, install, homebrew, java

If I have Oracle Java SE JDK 8 installed on my mac, how can I upgrade to Open JDK 8 and be sure it will be used by default?

Motivation: Android build tools seem to need JDK 8, but according to the following links Oracle JDK 8 will not receive free updates after January 2019 for commercial use, not even security updates:

- https://java.com/en/download/release_notice.jsp
- https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/637

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recommended prerequisite: check which versions of Java may already be installed using the following command: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

The following commands worked for me:

- `brew search openjdk` # check if desired `adoptopenjdk8` cask may already available
- `brew search java` # (optional)
- `brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk` # (assuming that the desired `adoptopenjdk8` cask is not already available)
- `brew search openjdk` # check that the desired `adoptopenjdk8` cask is now available
- `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8`

Then the following commands confirmed that I was using the desired OpenJDK 8 version by default (with no `JAVA_HOME` environment variable setting):

- `java -version`
- `javac -version`

And the following commands confirmed that I have both Java SE 8 and OpenJDK 8 installed:

- `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
- `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Note that `which java` and `which javac` show that `java` and `javac` are still run from `/usr/bin`.

Followup step: remove the old Java SE SDK from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, as documented in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903

AdoptOpenJDK 8 package notes May 2019: `adoptopenjdk8` was also added to `homebrew/cask-versions`, and this led to some issues: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/106

There is now a proposal to rename `adoptopenjdk8` to `openjdk8` in `homebrew/cask-versions`: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/pull/7375

If this proposal is merged, this answer will likely be updated to recommend installing the renamed cask.

See also (some references):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632292/how-to-install-specific-java-version-using-homebrew - discovered several months after I wrote this answer
- https://dzone.com/articles/install-openjdk-versions-on-the-mac - discovered after I wrote this answer, mostly good but shows some formulae that I did not see
- [How can I install java openjdk 8 on High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334384/how-can-i-install-java-openjdk-8-on-high-sierra/334385#334385)
- https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-install-openjdk-with-brew/712
- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk#other-versions
- https://medium.com/notes-for-geeks/java-home-and-java-home-on-macos-f246cab643bd
- [How to update Java from 8 Update 31 to 8 Update 51 when install fails?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196233/how-to-update-java-from-8-update-31-to-8-update-51-when-install-fails/196244#196244) - with an old answer with a very helpful link through which I found the page with Oracle JDK uninstall directions
- [Does Mountain lion download Apple's JDK or the OpenJDK when attempting to load a Java app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57378/does-mountain-lion-download-apples-jdk-or-the-openjdk-when-attempting-to-load-a) - interesting question from July 2012

Answer (score 0):

Use the adoptopenjdk cask

See also https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-install-openjdk-with-brew/712/4

To install latest:

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk
```

To install a specific version

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
```

**Manual Solution**

If you are looking to just bring down the binary without actually installing it, simply navigate to https://adoptopenjdk.net

Resources:
[How can I install java openjdk 8 on High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334384/how-can-i-install-java-openjdk-8-on-high-sierra/334385#334385)